# calling a function within a function--Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to call a function within another function.  I've created two arbitrary strings to match with a user created user name and password.  My first function is a login function that prompts the user to create a user name and password.  Once that is done, I will invoke my authenticate function to ensure the user created user name and password match up to the arbitrary strings.  However, I keep getting a 'userName' is not defined in the authenticate function, which I can understand why, but I'm still having trouble. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var arbName = "wolverine";
var arbPass = "marvel";

function login(){
    var userName = prompt ('enter username');
    var passWord = prompt ('enter password');
    authenticate (userName, passWord);
};

function authenticate(){
    if (userName === arbName && passWord === arbPass){
       alert ('true');
    }else {
       alert ('false');
    }
};
    login();
```

Comment: You should do some reading on variable scoping to know, which variables can be accessed from where.

Comment: Most definitely! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the username and password to the function as arguments, but you're not then using arguments in the receiving function. Add them as named arguments to the function declaration:

```
function authenticate(userName, passWord){
// Here --------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (userName === arbName && passWord === arbPass){
       alert ('true');
    }else {
       alert ('false');
    }
}
```

---

**Side note**: Function declarations are not statements, they don't need to be terminated with a `;` (although it's harmless if you do). Here are the three standard (for now) ways to create a function:

**Function declaration** (happens before any code in the scope runs, no semicolon, must be at top level of global or function scope [e.g., can't be directly inside a block associated with an `if` or `while` or similar):

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
```

**Anonymous function expression** (happens when it's encountered in the step-by-step evaluation of the code); examples:

```
var f = function() {
    // ...
};

var obj = {
    f: function() {
    }
};

bar(function() {
});
```

ES6 defines rules by which those functions can get names, and those rules are implemented by some engines now, but in theory the functions above have no names.

***Named* function expression** (NFE) (just like an anonymous one, but the fucntion gets a *name*):

```
var f = function foo() {
    // ...
};

var obj = {
    f: function foo() {
    }
};

bar(function foo() {
});
```

Some older engines [get this wrong](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) but they're fading now, thankfully.

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. And thanks for the sidenote.  I've been working out of chrome snippets, so I haven't had an issue with semi-colons following my functions but good to know

Answer (score 0):

You have to take **userName** and **passWord** as input parameters for the function **authenticate**.

like this:

```
function authenticate(userName, passWord){
    //your logic goes here
}
```